# replace with gsub in R

Tags: regex, r

I would like to convert string `\\xAB\\xAC` to `\xAB\xAC`in R.

When I'm using `gsub("\\\\", "$", x)` I'm getting `$AB$AC` which is expectable.
But when I'm using `gsub("\\\\", "\\", x)` I'm getting only `ABAC`.
Is where a way to workaround this?

Comment: Does your `x` contain two literal ``\`` before `x`? Or is it just 1 literal ``\``?

Comment: Actually, it is only a single \.  Try `cat(str1)`

Comment: See the helpfile `?backtick`; in particular, the **Character constants** section lists: \\ backslash \.

Comment: akrun was right. There appeared to be only one \ in `x`. When how about backward task? How to double it? `gsub("\\", '\\\\', x)` leads to 
`Error in gsub("\\", "\\\\", x) : 
  invalid regular expression '\', reason 'Trailing backslash'`

Comment: To double: `gsub("\\\\", "\\\\", x)`.

Comment: stribizhev, looks weird but this works.

Comment: Find: `"\\\\"` replace `"\\"` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per akrun's comment, you can use `cat(x)` to see/view the 'single' backslashed strings. The reason is that a single literal backslash is represented with two inside the R string literal. `cat` will "unescape" the string.

To double a single literal backslash,  use

```r
x <- "\\ backslash doubled here"
cat(gsub("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\", x), collapse="\n")
# => \\ backslash doubled here 
cat(gsub("\\", "\\\\", x, fixed=TRUE), collapse="\n")
# => \\ backslash doubled here
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/BrA1Y4).